# sed replace from csv include last character of search term

Tags: sed, docbook

I am trying to replace a list of words found in a csv file with index markup (docbook). The csv is in this format:

```
testword[ -?],testword<indexterm><primary>testword</primary></indexterm>
```

This finds all occurrences of the `testword` with punctuation at the end. This part works. However, I need the final punctuation mark to be included in the replace part of the sed command.

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)/s,\1,g/' index.csv > index.sed

sed -i -f index.sed file.xml
```

So e.g. `This is a testword, in a test.`
Would get replaced with `This is a testword,<indexterm><primary>testword</primary></indexterm> in a test.`

Comment: Do you want to have the entire range from `space` till `?` so including the numbers as punctuations?

Comment: is the csv file a generated file as well ? If not I would certainly think about generating it as well from a file with just the words you want to index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is the string in the csv file that steers the proces, here you loose the punctuation.
Replacing the:
`testword[ -?],testword<indexterm><primary>testword</primary></indexterm>`

by: 
`testword\([ -?]\),testword\1<indexterm><primary>testword</primary></indexterm>`

Would already solve your problem.

Comment: That worked. I just swapped the \1 to the end as I need the index next to the word.

`testword\([ -?]\),testword<indexterm><primary>testword</primary></indexterm>\1`

Comment: In the question the `,` was before replacement string, I found it already a bit odd. You can experiment with the string, it is just a way in the right direction.